# call the get_ method of the object

Tags: php, class, object, reflection, constructor

I have

```
foreach ($constructor_param_names as $reflectionParameter ){
            $constructor_params[] = $reflectionParameter -> getName();
            $property = $reflectionParameter -> getName();

//how to call the get____ method of the object
//to get the param value (of that parameter name)
            $value = $reflectionParameter-> ...
}
```

Comment: what is `param value (of that parameter name)`? Could you be more specific, please? I don't understand the question.

Comment: Do you mean the `__get` method? The [magic method](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php) [__get](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.get).

Comment: There is no `get_` method for objects. There *is* a `__get()` magic method for objects. Is this what you mean?

Comment: To be more specific i want to get back the value of the get function...  public function getAge()
    {
        return $this->age;
    }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is explained in the documentation for [variable methods](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php).

For an instance method:

```
$methodName = 'get_'.$property;
$value = $object->$methodName();
```

There are also other ways to call the getter (e.g. `call_user_func` and `ReflectionMethod::invoke`) but this is the most straightforward.

Also note that function and method names in PHP are *case-insensitive*, so there is no need to pay attention to capitalization.